# How to access the data of products whose available dates are set for future dates in Shopify Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-liquid

I have a store with products set to drop on different dates in the future. I have added those products in the Shopify store, but since those products are currently unavailable, the Product object is not listing them.

How can I access the unavailable products which are going to be available on future dates so I can show the users that those products are dropping on particular dates?

Comment: Have you tried with a collection? I'm not sure it would work though.

Comment: You could make them available but with zero inventory, so no one can buy them, assuming you also set the inventory policy to be not to sell zero inventory items. Put those items in a special collection as "future products" and you're good.